# Не срабатывает mysql запрос, но ошибок вообще нет

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Не пойму почему данные не добовляються в бд, хоть ошибок нет.

```
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $connection->connect_errno . ') '
        . $connection->connect_error);
}
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login = '$login'");
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    if($num == 0) {
        if ($connection->query("INSERT INTO `users` (login,password) VALUE 
    ('$login','$password')")) {
            header("Location: /app");
        } else {
            header("Location: ../register/register.php");
        }
    }else {
        header("Location: ../register/register.php");
    }


    $connection->close();
```

Возможно дело в файле htaccess вот его код.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://html-test.ru/error/404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
```

В самом начале вообще данные по методу POST не отправлялись, пока не добавил вторую строчку

Comment: Попробуйте 1) перед запросом с INSERT сделать $result->close(); 2) обработать и вывести ошибки выполнения $connection->query("INSERT ...")

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connection in E:\OSpanel\OSPanel\domains\html-test.ru\app\account\add-person.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in E:\OSpanel\OSPanel\domains\html-test.ru\app\account\add-person.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\OSpanel\OSPanel\domains\html-test.ru\app\account\add-person.php on line 14

Comment: Зачем вам эта строка `$connection->close()` ? Если до неё никогда не дойдет выполнение

Comment: Убрал, всё тоже самое..

Comment: РЕШИЛ, убрал просто кавы́чки VALUE ($login,$password,123)")